# Encrypt the password in selenium robot framework

Tags: excel, selenium, robotframework

I would like to encrypt my password, how is it possible in robot framework+selenium+python?

I am taking password from excel. any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Does this helps - https://michaelhallik.github.io/blog/2021/11/24/Robot-Framework-Crypto-Library

Comment: The encrypted value in the above link is passing directly in the script but I am taking the value from Excel and using to login. The problem here is, in Report the login details are shown, I would like mask the password and dont want to mask the action.

Comment: It does not mask the action. when you do enter the password it automaticaly decrypts it. It seems you have not tried the thread to its full extent.

Comment: I am getting error while trying the code in selenium - Error " CryptoError: An error occurred trying to decrypt the message"

I followed the steps given and generated a key. I passed the key in the script as below
*** Settings ***
Library    CryptoLibrary    variable_decryption=True

***variables***
${enc_pwd}    crypt:9EZHRho0X8P3ZoUK5isikYB/l9ojYUCi2cZxcjuxWNfNAAAxTpYqR+ItLwgeEd+B8XJP2Ncl77x0RtHN494YtA==

***Keywords***
${password}=    Get Decrypted Text    ${enc_pwd}
Input Password    ${txt_Password}     ${password}

Comment: Log -- [ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_test' of listener 'CryptoLibrary' failed: CryptoError: An error occurred trying to decrypt the message

Answer (score 0):

Try using Input.Password keyword where ever you are entering password
Input.Password will not print the password into report.

Refer:https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Input%20Password

Comment: Its still showing at the top of the report where it shows the arguments passed

Answer (score 0):

You can use b64encode   to encode the password
but you have to provide the real password once to encode it, once it is encrypted you can use it right away

Encrypt the password :

```
password= abc123
${encryptedPassword}    b64encode    ${password}
log to console  ${encryptedPassword}
```

Use the Encrypted password

```
${password} = <Paste The encrypted password here>
${password1}    b64decode  ${password}
input text ${xpath}  ${password1}
```

Comment: b64encode  is not taking in selenium, do we need to import any libraries?

Comment: use Library  base64

Comment: Getting Error 


KEYWORD ${encrypt_password} = base64 . B 64 Encode ${password} 








Documentation:

Encode the bytes-like object s using Base64 and return a bytes object.
 

Start / End / Elapsed:
20220214 10:06:24.706 / 20220214 10:06:24.707 / 00:00:00.001 

10:06:24.707 FAIL TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' 

************************************************code**********************************
${password}=           abc123


*** Test Cases ***
Trials
   ${encrypt_password}    B 64 Encode  ${password}
   Log    ${encrypt_password}

Answer (score 0):

you re gonna go to import the library
go to the terminal :
pip install pybase64

then
*** Settings ***
Library    pybase64

*** Variables ***

> ${password}     123456789

*** Keywords ***
hide the password

> ```
>   ${password1}     b64decode     ${password}
> ```

log to

> console     ${password1}